Film where protagonist spots his fake wife's contact lenses
I have very little memory of this film I'm afraid but here goes:
The scene I can remember has our protagonist in a coffee shop with a woman who is meant to be his wife, but is in fact an actor. At this point he's already suspicious that something is up, but the clinching moment is when he notices that his "wife" is wearing coloured contact lenses. 
It is an action film: at this point there is a sniper trained on the pair and iirc shooting breaks out after our hero spots the deception. 
Sorry I've got so little information here!

"Paycheck":
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0338337/
You can watch the complete movie here:



The cafe scene starts ca. at the 1:26:00 mark, and ca. at the 1:31:50 mark, after kissing the girl, Ben Affleck realizes that the girl wears contact lenses and she is not the real deal. Right after this scene you can see the sniper (played by Colm Feore) in a car, and there is a shootout, chase, etc. 
And here is an excerpt from an IMDb review:
"Apparently, during those three years, he strikes up a relationship with Uma. But, when another woman rendezvous with Ben at a Café, posing as Uma, he doesn't remember her at all. He should have known the woman was lying just by introducing herself as Uma. Regardless of the 3 year memory loss. He'd met her twice. But what does trigger his memory and makes him realize is that she's wearing contact lenses to change the color of her eyes."
I am sure this is the movie you are looking for. If you agree, then please mark my answer as Best Answer.

Yep that's definitely it! Cheers, good knowledge
